# A question concerning the Hilbert space trace

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am stuck with an equation regarding the trace on a Hilbert space $H$. The trace is defined in the book by Pedersen ("Analysis now", Sect. 3.4) as follows.

We choose an orthonormal basis $\{ e_j \mid j \in J\}$ for $H$, and for every positive operator $T \in B(H)$ (the latter denoting the space of bounded operators mapping $H$ to itself) we derfine the trace of $T$ by
$$
\text{tr}(T) = \sum \langle Te_j, e_j \rangle \,.
$$

One can show that 
$$ \tag1
\text{tr}(T^*T) = \text{tr}(TT^*)
$$
for every $T \in B(H)$, and from this one then shows that (Corollary 3.4.4. in Pedersen)
$$ \tag2
\text{tr}(UTU^*) = \text{tr}(T) \qquad \text{if $U$ is unitary and $T \ge 0$}\,.
$$
by using the fact that $T = (T^{1/2})^2$ together with replacing $T$ by $UT^{1/2}$ in equation (1). But here I am stuck, because from this I only get
\begin{align}
\text{tr}(UT^{1/2}(T^{1/2})^*U^*) &= 
\text{tr}((UT^{1/2})(UT^{1/2})^*) \\
&= \text{tr}((UT^{1/2})^*(UT^{1/2}))\\
&=  \text{tr}((T^{1/2})^*T^{1/2})
\end{align}
To conclude the identity (2) I need to assume that every positive operator $T$ can be written as $T = T^{1/2}(T^{1/2})^*$ .. is this correct ? If so, I'd love to understand why, how can I prove this? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, by continuous functional calculus. Set $T^{1/2}:=f(T)\in C^*(T)$ with $f(t)=\sqrt{t}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that since $T$ is a positive operator, it has a positive square root. A positive operator is self-adjoint, so $T^{\frac{1}{2}} = (T^{\frac{1}{2}})^*$. Therefore, you can decompose $T$ into $T^{\frac{1}{2}} T^{\frac{1}{2}} = T^{\frac{1}{2}} (T^{\frac{1}{2}})^*$.

Comment: The first sentence is proved in Pedersen, Proposition 3.2.11.